# Cocoapods dyld: Library not loaded @rpath Image not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, rpath

I am currently using Xcode 8.1, cocoa pods 1.2.0.beta.1, and launching my app on a simulator with iOS 10.1. My app builds just fine, however after launching the app in a simulator, I receive the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
  Referenced from:            /Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXX/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXX/XXXXX.app/XXXXX
  Reason: image not found
```

My Podfile is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

target "XXXXX" do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    ...

end

post_install do | installer |
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXXX/Pods-XXXXX-acknowledgements.plist', 'Pods-Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_desve_destination => true)
end
```

I have already tried de-integrating and re-installing my cocoa pods, changing the Pods-XXXXX.framework to optional, disabling Bitcode, and cleaning the workspace. None of those options (or any combination of them) has worked. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who find this issue in the future, it has been solved by cleaning the build folder by doing Option+Shift+Command+K. This solves the issue.

Comment: I wish it were this easy :(

Comment: @JiratPasuksmit try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491507/6108739)