# Library not loaded @rpath/AFNetworking iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, swift-custom-framework

I've facing very strange issue while installing my app onto device using custom (my own created) framework.

MyFramework uses AFNetworking, Dropbox and Google drive from pods, and I just dragged MyFramework into my app and just build(which is fine) but on installation this give me error

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers.../MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
  Reason: image not found`

MyApp has nothing just new app and added MyFramework into Embedded Binaries.

I googled and found many many solution (mostly say that delete drive data or Clean build). Even this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3986 own issue in github AFNetworking library, tried but no remedy.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm hitting the same issue..

Comment: @SandeepPhadke check my answer

Comment: Here's a solution that worked for me : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31810870/10390297](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31810870/10390297)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Find your `Target` --> `Build Phases` --> `Add New Copy Files Phase` -->`Choose Destination Option`,`Frameworks` --> `Click add AFNetworking.framework` --> Done.

Hope its useful.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to remove AFNetworking and install again, if you are using CocoaPods.

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.